# Trigger lambda from last 10 days of the month

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have a lambda that needs to be triggered daily at 5PM from 20th to 1st of every month. What would be the cron expression for it?

Comment: Use [Crontab.guru - The cron schedule expression editor](https://crontab.guru/#0_17_20-31,1_*_*) -- but be careful because it will use UTC, which might not be the timezone you are living in!

Comment: so you want from 20th of this month to 1st of next month right?

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa yes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cron expression (GMT Timezone):

```
0 17 20-1 * ? *
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use CloudWatch triggers to achieve this.
To create a rule using the console

Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

In the navigation pane, choose Events, Create rule.

For Event Source, do the following:

1. Choose Schedule.
2. Choose Fixed rate of and specify the schedule interval (for example, 5 minutes).
3. For Targets, choose Add target, Lambda function.
4. For Function, select the Lambda function that you created.
5. Choose Configure details.
6. For Rule definition, type a name and description for the rule.
7. Choose Create rule.

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Comment: What would be the `cron` expression  that needed to be used?

Comment: you can build your cron triggers here: http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node01ptbs8s6zomt4tz5z6snqvax1314356.node0?0